# Remove words/ lines between matching delimeters

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7

how is it possible to remove the lines between `start` and `end` including those matching words.

```
line1
line2
start
line3
line4
line5
line6
end
line7
line8
```

Result I would expect is:-

```
line1
line2
line7
line8
```

I tried the following code but nothing seems to be working.

```
text = "line1\nline2\nstart\nline3\nline4\nline5\nline6\nend\nline7\nline8"
print re.sub(r'start(.*)end', '',  text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use the modifier `re.DOTALL` to make the `(.*)` match newlines:

```
re.sub(r'start(.*)end', '',  text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

And then, I think it's safer to use a lazy `(.*?)` just in case you have something like:

```
line1\nstart\nline2\nline3\nend\nline4\nline5\nstart\nline6\nend\nline7
```

Which without `(.*?)` will remove everything from the first `start` to the last `end` including the part not between `start` and `end` in the middle:

```
re.sub(r'start.*?end', '',  text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Last, I remove the parentheses because they're not actually needed here.

If you want to remove all the blanks that's left behind, use `\s*` to trim them:

```
re.sub(r'start.*?end\s*', '',  text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Working perectly. Jerry you saved me again.:-))

Comment: @sundar_ima You're welcome :) Consider [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)ing the answers that you believe worked for you in order to mark your problem as solved.

Comment: @sundar_ima Oh right, I always forget about the countdown xD Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `.` character does *not* match newlines by default. You need to enable that by setting the [`re.DOTALL` flag](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

```
>>> text = "line1\nline2\nstart\nline3\nline4\nline5\nline6\nend\nline7\nline8"
>>> print re.sub(r'start(.*)end', '',  text, flags=re.DOTALL)
line1
line2

line7
line8
```

Note that there is a blank line between; you'd need to include the newline *after* `end` too:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'start(.*)end\n', '',  text, flags=re.DOTALL)
line1
line2
line7
line8
```

As an alternative to `.`, you could also use two opposing character classes together:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'start([\s\S]*)end\n', '',  text)
line1
line2
line7
line8
```

Here `\s` and `\S` together capture *all* characters, including newlines, without the `DOTALL` flag being set.

You may want to make your match non-greedy. If you have **two** sets of `start` and `end` lines in your input, then the `.*` will match all text from the first `start` all the way to the last `end`:

```
>>> text = 'line1\nstart\nline2\nend\nline3\nstart\nline4\nend\nline5'
>>> print text
line1
start
line2
end
line3
start
line4
end
line5
>>> print re.sub(r'start(.*)end\n', '',  text, flags=re.DOTALL)
line1
line5
```

Note how `line3` is gone too. Alter the `*` by adding a question mark, making it non-greedy:

```
>>> print re.sub(r'start(.*?)end\n', '',  text, flags=re.DOTALL)
line1
line3
line5
```